# Why do the Balanced Payments docs say HTTPS is required, but it doesn't seem to be?

Tags: balanced-payments

If I use a simple `rails c` command to open my development console, and fetch my customers with:

`Balanced::Customer.all`

I not only get results, but I can use:

```
customer = Balanced::Customer.all.first
customer.name = "Joe Bob"
customer.save # this works, returns true
customer = Balanced::Customer.all.first
puts customer.name
```

And the result will indeed be "Joe Bob".

I'm not sure what exactly `"For security concerns regarding submitted data, all your requests MUST occur via https."` means, if it doesn't seem to be true... Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: If you can access customer information, you should always have an HTTPS connection. The system answering your requests may not check and still give you the information. It just isn't safe if you do so on HTTP because all the data is publicly readable. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @AlexisWilke, yes it seems that they simply meant that as a disclaimer, rather than "our service doesn't work over http". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The request your system is making to the Balanced API occurs over HTTPS. It does not mean that you need to run a web server over HTTPS however, it would be strongly recommended.

Comment: See my response to @remear

Answer (score 1):

The interactions between your Rails application and Balanced always take place over HTTPS. The part of the documentation you quoted is referring to these interactions. This does not remove the need for you to use SSL on your servers in production as all financial transactions should occur over SSL.

Comment: This makes much more sense. Due to how this is worded I spent an evening setting up my local environment to be HTTPS thinking Balanced rejected any non-SSL requests even in dev and test environments. Could this wording be updated to prevent throwing anyone else off? Thanks for the info!